# Why android:actionBarDivider doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Having

```
<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/action_bar_divider</item>
```

in my Activity style has zero effect. Doesn't matter if I'm using native ActionBar or ActionBarSherlock. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around it by programatically inserting dividers into the view hierarchy. It occured to me later that dividers may be only visible in the bottom action bar (I needed them at the top bar). But I didn't verify that.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int id : new int[] { R.id.action_1, R.id.action_2 }) {
                View actionView = findViewById(id);
                insertDividerBefore(actionView);
            }
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Comment: "programatically inserting dividers into the view hierarchy" - Could you edit your answer with an example of how you did that?

Comment: Q1) Just to make it clear `R.id.action_1` and `R.id.action_2` are the IDs defined in `R.menu.main_acitivity`, right?

Comment: Q2) Another thing... I'm sure this works fine for the "normal" ActionBar, what about the Contextual ActionBar (CAB)? For instance, in ICS, if you long-press some text in a EditText widget, the ActionBar will change to a different when where you can select/copy/paste text. What do you do in this CAB? Since I'm styling the buttons background, they also get used in the CAB buttons and all these buttons really need a divider on the left side of the button.

Comment: A2) With CAB there shouldn't be much difference. In ActionMode.Callback#onCreateActionMode(...) do the similar thing as I'm doing in onCreateOptionsMenu(...).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15731/discussion-between-ricardo-amaral-and-fhucho)

Comment: Perhaps you could use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(android.view.ActionMode.Callback) to customize the copy/paste CAB.

Answer (score 0):

> **android:actionBarDivider**
>     Defines a drawable resource for the divider between action items. (Added in API level 14.)

Make sure whether you are using API level 14 or later.

Comment: Yes, my target API version is 15.